# How to set Many-to-Many relation with custom id name with TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, typescript, many-to-many, typeorm

I have a user, role and user_role table.

When i make @ManyToMany relation i get an error when i try to join the tables because the query uses "roleId" but i named it "role_id" and i cant figure out how to set the column name.

```
// User.ts

@ManyToMany(type => Role, role => role.users)
@JoinTable({name: 'user_role'})
roles?: Role[];
```

```
// Role.ts

@ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.roles)
@JoinTable({name: 'user_role'})
users: User[];
```

The UserService to query:

```
    public static getAllByRole(role: RoleEnum): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.userRepository()
            .createQueryBuilder('user')
            .leftJoinAndSelect(
                'roles',
                'role',
                'role.user_id = user.id'
            ).where('role.role_id = :id', {id: role})
            .getMany();
    }
```

I expect to get all users with a specific role e.g "Admin".

But it throws an error:

```
console.log node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js:193
    query failed: INSERT INTO "user_role"("roleId", "userId") VALUES ($1, DEFAULT), ($2, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: ["ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"]

  console.log node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js:193
    error: { error: column "roleId" of relation "user_role" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

```
// User.ts

    @Field(type => [Role])
    @ManyToMany(type => Role, role => role.users)
    @JoinTable({
        name: 'user_role', joinColumn: {
            name: 'user_id',
            referencedColumnName: 'id'
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
            name: 'role_id',
            referencedColumnName: 'id'
        }
    })
    roles?: Role[];


// Role.ts

    @ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.roles)
    @JoinTable({
        name: 'user_role',
        joinColumn: {
            name: 'role_id',
            referencedColumnName: 'id'
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
            name: 'user_id',
            referencedColumnName: 'id'
        }
    })
    users: User[];
```

Comment: Very odd, in the docs says you can't use @JoinTable from both entities

Comment: Yes I should removed it from Role.ts. I'm even dont need it there.